# Bluemix CLI error "The client is not yet configured."

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I am trying to log in to the Bluemix Container Service with cmd.exe. I installed the latest Bluemix CLI and IBM Bluemix Container Service plug-in, and tried to login using the following command:

```
C:\>bx login -a api.ng.bluemix.net
...
OK
...

C:\>bx cs init --host https://us-south.containers.bluemix.net
The IBM Bluemix Container Service Kubernetes beta in the US South region (Dallas) has concluded. You can access your bet
a clusters via the CLI using (bx cs init --host https://us-south-beta.containers.bluemix.net).  See https://ibm.biz/cont
ainer-migration for beta migration information.

Using user provided API endpoint: https://us-south-beta.containers.bluemix.net
OK

C:\>bx cs clusters
The IBM Bluemix Container Service Kubernetes beta in the US South region (Dallas) has concluded. You can access your bet
a clusters via the CLI using (bx cs init --host https://us-south-beta.containers.bluemix.net).  See https://ibm.biz/cont
ainer-migration for beta migration information.

FAILED
The client is not yet configured. Run `bx login`.
```

The Bluemix login was successful, but an error occurred. I tried it with bash on Windows, but the results were the same.

Comment: It looks all confused between us-south-beta and us-south - even though you login to api.ng, and init us-south, it gives us-south-beta.  If I try it I get: `Using user provided API endpoint: https://us-south.containers.bluemix.net`. Does `bx api` list correct target? Did you actually use the beta?

Comment: Agreed - very odd that the endpoint it calls it is different from the one you specified.  What version of the plugin are you using?  Should be something like: `Plugin Name    Version : container-service    0.1.259`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have not used beta version. I use `bx plugin list` and `bx --version` to ensure version of them are accurate. It returns `container-service version 0.1.259`, and `bx version 0.5.4`. Then I rekey: `bx cs init --host https://us-south.containers.bluemix.net`, it returns: `Using user provided API endpoint: https://us-south.containers.bluemix.net`. Sorry, it may be that I made a mistake copying text. The same error occurred even in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install Cloud Foundry CLI instead of Bluemix CLI and work hope your problem gets resolved.